# how to convert QR code to img and save it to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using qrcode.react to create a qrcode.

```
<QRCode value="something.pdf||someFirbaselink||TestCompany" />
```

how can I convert this to image and save it to firebase storage

```
qrRef.put(<QRCode value="something.pdf||someFirbaselink||TestCompany" />)
.then(snapshot => {

});
```

the code above won't work.

Comment: Just a thought wouldn't the efficient way be to store and fetch that data needed to make the QR Code in the database and use a QR code library on the client to display it instead of all that network traffic cost for images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [stackoverflow answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35502019/1614889) shows another library that can be used that will give you base64Data which can be used to upload to firebase storage.

[Docs for the library called QRious](https://neocotic.com/qrious/)

**Code sample of how to create the QR Code and then upload to firebase**

```
const qr = new QRious();
qr.value = 'https://neocotic.com/qrious';

var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var ref = storageRef.child('qr.png');
ref.putString(qr.toDataURL(), 'data_url').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a data_url string!');
});
```